# scope of 'angular' variable when several apps are declared?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

if you have the following:

```
<html ng-app="outerApp">
<head ng-app="innerApp"></head>
<script>
   var outerApp = angular.module("outerApp", []);
   var ACtrl = outerApp.controller("ACtrl", function($scope){console.log($scope.name);});
   var BCtrl = outerApp.controller("BCtrl",function($scope){console.log($scope.name});
   var CCtrl = innerApp.controller.("CCtrl", function($scope){ console.log($scope.name);});
   var innerApp = angular.module("innerApp", []);
 </scope>
```

Is this ok?  is angular a global variable that will work for declaring modules out of both innerApp and outerApp?  Also are there limits to number of ng-app's on a page?  And do both ACtrl, and BCtrl have reference to the same $scope?

Thanks

Comment: The way you're defining the controllers seems fine but having an `ng-app` inside an `ng-app` seems strange and I'm not sure it would behave well. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: well mainly looking to have different $scope. So I was thinking nested apps might created an inner and outer scope object ... Looks nested apps cannot be done but still wondering about creating an inner and outer $scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because:

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead. **AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.**

See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

Answer (score 1):

$rootscope,$scope are conceptually global variables, whom you can implement to achieve as global variables for sharing data between the modules,directives,controllers,views.

you should read conceptually DI(Dependency Injection) and how the conceptual framework implements in angular. you can inject the dependencies.

angular.module('modulename',[]);
[] is an array in which you define that module is dependant on the other module. in Other words.
Angular framework concepts works the injectable way DI(Dependency Inject).

however i strongly suggest you, what you trying to achieve is the right path is, you should make a simple custom directive and inject it as a dependency in the angular app.